# Angular Ivy - Really Bad Performance Benchmark

Tags: angular, performance, typescript, angular-ivy

I am developing performance benchmarks for angulars new ivy renderer and almost every test at least performs 1.5 times worse than with the old renderer. What may cause this issue?

All the benchmarks were implemented using the exact same angular project (version 8.0.0 Beta-11), the only difference between the benchmarks was, that i enabled the ivy renderer by using the "enableIvy": true flag.

The ivy renderer seems to be getting exponentially worse with the amount of elements i modify in my benchmark. Adding 1.000 elements results in a 1.5 times worse benchmark in the new ivy renderer while adding 10.000 new elements already triples the performance deficit with ivy.

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "enableIvy": true,
  "allowEmptyCodegenFiles": true
}
```

The results i expect from googles benchmarks are:
 (1) dramatically reduced bundle sizes and
 (2) better performance with ivy than with the old view renderer

Sources:
https://youtu.be/jnp_ny4SOQE?t=2263
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/25569

Comment: Ivy's goal has never been to increase runtime performance. And the current version is 8.0.0-rc.2. I wouldn't expect dramatically reduced bundle size either, unless you have a helloworld application using only a tiny part of what Angular provides.

Comment: "enableIvy" option is not yet recommended.
check this article : https://juristr.com/blog/2019/05/Angular-8-and-the-Future-NGConf-2019-Roundup/

Comment: @skiabox Thank you so much. This is even a better outcome than i could have hoped for in my thesis.